# Laravel; how make setLocale permanent?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I've my home route

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

And a specific route to change language

```
Route::get('/setLocale/{locale}', 'HomeController@setLocale')->name('setLocale');
```

In `HomeController->setLocale($locale)` I check if `$locale` is a valid locale, then simply do

```
\App::setLocale($locale);
```

Then redirect to home.

Here, in `HomeController->index()` I verify locale using

```
$locale = \App::getLocale();
```

The problem is that after user CHANGES the locale, the app set the new locale, redirect, but the locale detected is still the DEFAULT locale, not the new one setup by the user.

How / where / when can I make persistent the change to app locale?

I thinked Laravel was setting a locale cookies or something when using `setLocale` and re-reading it when using `getLocale` but now I think it's not this the way Laravel works.

I ask, again: how can I set app locale so that is preserved after page change?

Comment: Use session/cache to store locale `\App:setLocale('ufo-language')` sets locale only for request life. Anyway use routes for it and do not save anything for search engine sake.

Comment: Customer asked me to avoid locale slug. He preferred the url translation

Comment: Does your customer know all the ramifications? It seems stupid but if there is a translation for site, google will never know, since it seems that g-bot does not store cookies. Cheers

Comment: We exports sitemap. google will known every page. Also, every controller use the url segmemts to identify the language. Very bad idea, but customer want it

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I did that by using a middleware. Here's my code:

LanguageMiddleware:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if(session()->has('locale'))
        app()->setLocale(session('locale'));
    else 
        app()->setLocale(config('app.locale'));

    return $next($request);
}
```

remember to register your middleware :)

The users are able to change the language, with a simple GET-Route:

```
Route::get('/lang/{key}', function ($key) {
    session()->put('locale', $key);
    return redirect()->back();
});
```

Hopefully that helps you :)

Apparently, there are some changes in Laravel 7.0!

If you are using the code above, please change from a BeforeMiddleware to a AfterMiddleware! (see https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/middleware)

If you don't do this, the value of `session('locale')` will always be null!

Comment: This works also in Laravel 9.x

Comment: Are you refering to my comment about Laravel 7? Or did they change something again? (hopefully not)

Answer (score 4):

`setlocale` only works for the current request. If you want the value to be remembered, you will have to set a cookie manualy.

I recommend using a [middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/middleware) to do this.

Comment: What about simply set in the boot of the app?

Comment: Depends if all the routes in your app are translated and require a personal locale.