# App:setLocale() doesn't translate on Laravel

Tags: laravel

Trying to do a switcher of languages, but it doesn't work. Help me, where is the problem? It doesn't translate after switching.

```
Route::get('/locale', function () {
  $locale = App::getLocale();
  $locale = ($locale == 'ro') ? 'ru' : 'ro';
  App::setLocale($locale);
  return redirect('/');
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work too. `Route::get('/locale', function () {
    $locale = App::isLocale('ru') ? 'ro' : 'ru';
    App::setLocale($locale);
    return redirect('/');
});`

Answer (score 2):

After you set the locale, you redirect and Laravel takes the default locale from the settings again.

I guess what you are looking for, is to save the setting in a session.
This is already answered in: [Laravel; how make setLocale permanent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44456027/laravel-how-make-setlocale-permanent)

Another way, is to have the language in your URL (`ro.example.com/home` or `example.com/ru/home`)

Answer (score 0):

Because you are redirecting after setting your locale.

So you are making a new request, and the default locale is going to be set.

You should move that logic to a Middleware.

Comment: So I need all urls with language prefix to use? something like example.com/en/controller/action ? Or can I do something like switcher?

Comment: You can create a Language Middleware, were you just need to put that locate snippet. And attach that Middleware to the routes that you need.